# Advantages of Fluid Bed Drying

Tags: drying

One of the advantages of fluid bed drying especially in the pharma industry is the “Turbulence in the bed causes mild attrition to particles thus producing more spherical free flowing product.”

This is from the textbook and I don’t understand the meaning behind it. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 2):

It means that the particles rub and bounce against each other, which removes any “odd” bits that may otherwise cling to the proper surface of the particle.